# Using ffplay as a C++ library?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I want to be able to use the functionality of ffplay as a C++ library, as opposed to a standalone command line tool. Right now in C++, I am able to call ffplay via `std::system`, but this isn't [ideal for performance](https://cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/282893/) as is documented extensively here, chief of which is simply that we need to spawn new shell processes in order to execute this.

My application attempts to feed in a bytestream of audio data to a media player. Running a command like `cat /tmp/f.mp3 | ffplay -v 0 -nodisp -autoexit -` runs smoothly but somewhat slowly/not instantaneously. I would ideally like to be able pass in a bytestream to an `ffplay` function or via some library that I can link directly to my application. I think `ffplay` is quite useful here, as it integrates `ffmpeg` and `SDL` together.

Is this possible at all? Or is the only hope to use the command line functionality?

Comment: The source code is available. https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/fftools/ffplay.c You could use that as a reference to add the functionality you need to your program.

Comment: [`libmpv`](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/DOCS/man/libmpv.rst) not working for some reason?